# Rails form builder not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, nested-forms, railscasts

I am trying to reproduce the functionality as demonstrated in [railscast episode 196 Nested Model Form](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) which is quite old.

The problem i am facing is that, Rails is currently displaying only one instance of question and choices instead of 3.

In my app the relevant models are paper, question and choice.

Relevant code chunks:

`app/controllers/papers_controller.rb`

```
def new
  @paper = Paper.new
  3.times do
    question = @paper.questions.build
    3.times { question.choices.build }
  end
end
```

[app/views/papers/_form](https://github.com/beyond2013/ots/blob/complexform/app/views/papers/_form.html.erb) too long to be posted here

[app/views/papers/_question_fields](https://github.com/beyond2013/ots/blob/complexform/app/views/papers/_question_fields.html.erb)

[app/views/papers/_choice_fields](https://github.com/beyond2013/ots/blob/complexform/app/views/papers/_choice_fields.html.erb)

For complete app code see [github repo](https://github.com/beyond2013/ots/tree/complexform/).

Comment: could you please also share your views?

Comment: @Prakash I have included links to views and the entire repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line causing the problem was in `app/views/papers/_form`.

Replacing  `<%= form.fields_for :question do |builder| %>`
with `<%= form.fields_for :questions  do |builder| %>`

solved the issue.